# Keyable index of an image sequence?

Tags: shader-nodes

I'm looking for a way to use and key specific images of an image sequence, rather than play them in order. The proper image sequence nodes isn't keyable, and doing it manually with mix nodes isn't realistic for a large number of pictures. Is there a good solution to this, making a node with an keyable integer that would output image 1, 2... in the sequence?

Comment: take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq3RiZvqXMg) it might be useful.

Comment: Of course the solution is to negate the node's value :D thanks